# PrintWriter isn't writing to a file, but the split() seems to be working correctly?

Tags: java, printwriter

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class ProjectTwoAccessControl{


 // public static void fOrAAdd(String x,PrintWriter n){
//      n.write(x);
//  }


public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{
    PrintWriter friends = new PrintWriter("friends.txt"); 
    PrintWriter audit = new PrintWriter("auditlog.txt");



try {
FileInputStream inputCommands;

    inputCommands = new FileInputStream("test.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputCommands));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){ //2
        String[] command = line.split(" ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(command));
//      for(int i = 0; i < command.length;i++){ //1
        if (command[0] == "friendadd"){
            friends.write(command[1]);
            audit.write("Friend " + command[1] + " was added.");

        }
//      } //1

} //2
}//try end
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("No file found by this name");
}
    friends.close();
    audit.close();

} 








}
```

I am attempting to make a social media style of access control for a school assignment, and am going to continue working on this all evening, but I cannot figure out why the PrintWriters are not writing. I added in to print the array "command" out, and it seems to be working correctly, but nothing will print to my friends.txt or audit.txt.

Comment: Maybe try flushing the printwriter after every line to make sure any pending changes are written.

Comment: Tom you were right, Thank you.

Answer (score -3):

zack is right you need to call flush() on the PrintWriter because close() does not call flush()

Comment: And why do you think that there is something in the buffer which needs to be flushed?